# How to uncheck RadioButton if already checked in RadioGroup

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I have two RadioButtons in RadioGroup, initially both are unchecked. I want to uncheck RadioButton if it is already checked. I have tried but I'm unable to do it. When I choose any radio button then it is not changing state to checked first time, if I select same radio button second time then it is changing its state, and if I select other radio button if one button is checked then it is also not changing the state first time and all button get unchecked can anyone help me? My code is given below...

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {
RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton)group.findViewById(checkedId);
pus="";

boolean isChecked = checkedRadioButton.isChecked();
 if(isChecked){
     checkedRadioButton.setChecked(false);

 }else{
     checkedRadioButton.setChecked(true);

 }
}
 Toast.makeText(context, pus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
```

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rdbt_group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio_no"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/rbtn_selector"
    android:button="@null"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:textColor="@drawable/rbtn_textcolor_selector"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

    <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio_yes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:button="@null"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:background="@drawable/rbtn_selector"
    android:textColor="@drawable/rbtn_textcolor_selector"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: If I am not wrong You want that If User clicks same checked RadioButton again, it should clear the selection, right ?

Comment: yes you are right...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncheck radio button if already checked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132111/uncheck-radio-button-if-already-checked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RadioGroup is mean for selecting one of two option, you should not disturb regular behavior of views. User compulsorily choice one of option from two. consider gender as radiogroup , there may be two or three option you have to choice one of them compulsorily. This can be achieve by simply adding below code in xml

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

    <RadioButton
      android:id="@+id/radioButton"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="RadioButton"
      tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="126dp"
      tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="83dp"/>

    <RadioButton
      android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="RadioButton"
      tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="172dp"
      tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="127dp"/>
  </RadioGroup>
```

and in activity class

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
            // you can check if radiobutton is checked or unchecked here , do needful codes
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 13):

I know it's a bit late to answer this question but still, if it can help someone else I would be glad.

Just make a custom class extending `RadioButton` or `AppCompatRadioButton` and override `toggle()` method.

```
public class UncheckableRadioButton extends AppCompatRadioButton {

    public UncheckableRadioButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public UncheckableRadioButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public UncheckableRadioButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {

        if (isChecked()) {
            if (getParent() != null && getParent() instanceof RadioGroup) {
                ((RadioGroup) getParent()).clearCheck();
            }
        } else {
            super.toggle();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getAccessibilityClassName() {
        return UncheckableRadioButton.class.getName();
    }
}
```

And this will also work if you check `radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()`.

Answer (score 2):

I had just one radio button and I really didn't want to make a radio button group. The onClick and if and else check was not working to manually check and uncheck it. I read a couple of posts with onRadioButtonClick listeners etc.

First I tried to swap to checkbox-> same problem. Then I tried the CheckedTextView and what do you know, it actually worked like a toggle. So basically I added a radio button then left the text empty, added the checkedTextView next to it (overlapping) then linked the onClick function of the checkedTextView to a toggle function ->

```
public void toggle(View view)
{ 
    if(checkedTextView.isChecked())
    { 
        checkedTextView.setChecked(false); 
        actualRadioBtn.setChecked(false);
    }
    else
    {
        checkedTextView.setChecked(true);
        actualRadioBtn.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

Then in your function where you check if that radio button is selected you can simply use

```
if(actualRadioBtn.isChecked())....
```

Comment: Have you looked at Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

You can't "uncheck" a radio button. But you can clear a [`RadioGroup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) using [`clearCheck`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#clearCheck()).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use **CheckBox** rather. Hope it helps

Comment: Can you provide more details how why CheckBox is a better choice? TIA.

Comment: Yeah sure. You can actually uncheck checkbox by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to uncheck checked radio buttons.

Create an instance variable to store last checked radio button id:

```
int lastChecked = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

Then:

```
View.OnClickListener radioClick = radioButton -> {
    if( radioButton.getId() == lastChecked ) {
        radioGroup.clearCheck();
    }
};
findViewById(R.id.radio_no).setOnClickListener(radioClick);
findViewById(R.id.radio_yes).setOnClickListener(radioClick);

radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener((group, checked) -> {
    group.post(() -> {
        lastChecked = checked;
    });
});
```